# Selenium scraping: Wall Street Journal doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrape

I need help regarding selenium web scraping.

Basically, I was trying to scrape news titles and news links from Wall Street Journal's world section - https://www.wsj.com/news/world.

But it doesn't work. There is no iframe issue, I think.

Please help me. Thx.

My code:

```
# import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os

# set environment
desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
e_driver_path = desktop_path + r"\msedgedriver.exe"

# Xpath
xpath_wsj_world_s1_v1nt = ['//*[@id="top-news"]/article/div[2]/div[2]/h2/a/span',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/article/div[3]/h3/a/span',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[3]/h3/a/span',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/article/div[3]/h3/a/span',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/article/div[3]/h3/a/span',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/article/div[3]/h3/a/span']
xpath_wsj_world_s1_v1nu = ['//*[@id="top-news"]/article/div[2]/div[2]/h2/a',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/article/div[3]/h3/a',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/article/div[3]/h3/a',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/article/div[3]/h3/a',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/article/div[3]/h3/a',
                            '//*[@id="top-news"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/article/div[3]/h3/a']

def wsj_world():

    ############################################ Enter the website
    # targeted website
    website_link = 'https://www.wsj.com/news/world'

    # establish the web driver
    s = Service(e_driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)

    # pass web links to the driver
    driver.get(website_link)

    ############################################ Load more contents
    # scroll down to load the full web contents
    time.sleep(1.5)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2000)")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 4000)")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 7000)")
    time.sleep(1.5)

    ############################################ container for all news in the section
    nt = []     # news title
    nu = []     # news url

    ############################################
    section = "WSJ World: Head"
    result = []
    # xpath
    xpath_t = [xpath_wsj_world_s1_v1nt]
    xpath_u = [xpath_wsj_world_s1_v1nu]

    # iterate the xpath
    try:
        for x, y in zip(xpath_t[0], xpath_u[0]):
            # news title getting text
            a = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

            b = a.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x)))
            c = b.text      # .get_attribute('textContent')
            nt.append(c)

            b = a.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, y)))
            c = b.get_attribute('href')
            nu.append(c)
    except:
        result.append("Failed")
        pass

    # print out title and url
    for x, y in zip(nt, nu):
        print(x, y)

    # save data
    return nt, nu

wsj_world()
```

I followed the same process to scrape news titles and news URLs from BBC and Sky News.
But it doesn't work in the WSJ scenario.
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

In this case we can do the job simply with list comprehension

```
main_article = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article h2 a")
other_articles = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article h3 a")
articles = main_article + other_articles
titles = [article.text for article in articles]
links = [article.get_attribute('href') for article in articles]

for i in range(len(titles)):
    print(titles[i]+'\n'+links[i]+'\n')
```

output

```
Sour U.S.-China Relations Feed the Fentanyl Crisis
https://www.wsj.com/articles/fentanyl-crisis-fed-by-flow-of-chinese-chemicals-to-mexican-cartels-11671722056?mod=world_lead_story

Islamic State Suspected to Be Behind Series of Attacks in Iraq
https://www.wsj.com/articles/islamic-state-suspected-to-be-behind-series-of-attacks-in-iraq-11671723777?mod=world_lead_pos1

Russia Blames Ukraine for Attack on Leaders Deep in Occupied Territory
https://www.wsj.com/articles/russia-blames-ukraine-for-attack-on-leaders-deep-in-occupied-territory-11671710139?mod=world_lead_pos2

...
```